# Using Route-Me to as Mapping Alternative

Tags: iphone, android-mapview, route-me

I would like to user route-me in a mapping application because I need to support disconnected use 90% of the time.

I have looked at their tutorials, but I am looking for how to download tiles and store them on my device so the application works with no network connectivity at all.

If I missed a similar question in stackoverflow, I apologize in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use RMMBTilesTileSource

Check out this example from the folks over at mapbox (also they have a great tool for creating mbtile [sqlite] db's too)
https://github.com/mapbox/mbtiles-ios-example

Ciao!